# How to extract only the first and last numerical value from a txt file, in python?

Tags: python, txt

I have a txt file of this type:

```
1,23,4,5
4.6,5,7,8.9
2,3,45,21
2,4.2,5,6
58,a,b,c,d
d,e,f,g,h
```

I want to extract only the first and the last numerical value. in my next program I was able to delete the characters from the string and get a string with the numbers:

```
import re
with open("C:\testo.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        x=lines[i]
        result=re.match('\d+', x)
        if result != None:
           valori=result.group()
           print(valori)
```

my output is:

```
1
23
4
5
4.6
5
7
8.9
2
3
45
21
2
4.2
5
6
58
```

now the output I want is :

```
1 
58
```

Comment: you should use `if result is not None` because using `!=` can cause problems

Comment: You should also directly iterate over lines ```for l in lines:```

Comment: That can't be the output of your code... Your code would only output ***the first*** number of each line and can't recognize floats for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `if result != None:` instead of printing the result you could append it to a list

`resultList.append(valori)`

then you would get the first and last value by slicing the list

for the first item
`resultList[0]`

for the last item
`resultList[-1]`

Comment: The last item can be accessed in a more pythonic way using ```resultList[-1]```

Comment: fair enough----

Comment: what is resultList?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an additional list.

```
if result != None:
       lst_valori.append(result.group())
```

Output

```
>> lst_valori[0]
1
>> lst_valori[-1]
58
```

Comment: Please note that while your solution based on the question is good, but there is a problem with OP's code and the output is not correct. If the line in the file would be `58,59,a,b,c,d` this won't work

Comment: what is lst_valori?

Comment: it's an empty list declared before the for loop. `lst_valori = []`.

Comment: I declared the list like this: lst_values=[], but then it gives me the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'match'

Answer (score 0):

No need to read the whole file in memory: one row at a time is enough

```
first = None
last = None
with open("C:\testo.txt") as fp:
    for row in fp:
        for el in row.split(','):
            try:
                n = float(el)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            last = el
            if first is None:
                first = el

print(first, last)
```

Comment: in this way it prints me 1 and h, I want to print the first and last NUMERIC value

Comment: I have just tried it now, it works fine, gives me 1 and 58

Comment: ditch Windows (just half-joking, I have no idea. It works fine on Linux). You might have weird characters in the input